# Analyze relationship between two layers of points?

Tags: qgis

I have a layer of points that are patients who were readmitted to the hospital and a layer of points of patients who were not readmitted to the hospital.

I want to find geographical factors that influence this readmission. Some of the factors that I have GIS information: distance to fast food, fitness centers, churches, grocery stores

Using distance, what would be an efficient and logical way to analyze this data on QGIS?

Comment: Do you have some background on statistical approach? (like PCA and such). Because have an idea but I really see that the other way round. You could use QGIS to populate fields that you would then inject into a statistical tool.

Comment: may be something like "Using a Geographical Explanations Machine to Explore Spatial Factors relating to Primary School Performance" http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/13615930120032635?journalCode=cgem20

Answer (score 3):

​
I know this will be an underwhelming answer but here is my proposal:

- Get contact info of patients of both groups and launch a phone survey
- Ask whether they have easy access to fast food on their daily routine
- Also ask if they are regulars customers of such restaurants.

Yeah, I know this is not an answer using GIS, but this might actually the easiest path to gather meaningful insights for your study. So next part of my answer will focus on why using GIS is not a good idea VS a survey according to current technology and your available dataset.

---

So here are the foreseeable caveats of using GIS to determine exposition to fast food.

1. Fast food database must be as accurate as possible. Thing is there is still differences between database vendors and you'll have to make a choice. The more universal database might be open street map, but they offer no completeness guarantee because it's crowd sourced. So no matter which one you choose, you might want to spend some time on validating your POI database before any analysis.
2. Knowing only residential address of your patients is not sufficient to determine if they are exposed to fast food. They might have access at workplace, or on commuting route, dropping kid to school, shopping, etc
3. The sole concept of accessibility may vary between individuals. If they don't own a car for instance the radius in which to seek for fast food must be more limited. (but if they use public transportation, they might actually be more exposed because fast food are sometimes implanted in big exchanges stations)
4. Lastly (and you saw it coming) people don't move around town flying in straight line. So should you be fine with precedings caveats, you'd still have to use something more accurate than a radius buffer and use some routing algorithm to determine each patient theoretical accessible area.

Of course I'm assuming that you dataset include some city's in it. Maybe your dataset cover only a very rural area and you only need to know if there is a fast-food in the same city as your patient live. Then most off theses caveats are irrelevant. But so is GIS approach then cause this will more look like a boolean test and don't really need spatial analysis.

---

So IMHO while it might even be pretty easy to overlay patients data with fastfood location, determining actual correlation between the two dataset is a pretty long-shot. So it all depend if you aim a rational and rigorous scientific approach or a buzz article about magical bigdata unicorn.

A good old survey can't be beaten by GIS on this one I think.

Comment: +1, definitely **not** an underwhelming answer =)

Answer (score 2):

One pretty basic method is to create a **2-score system** in terms of the proximity of each point to its influential factor. The aim would be to see if a point from the "Non-readmitted layer" lies within the maximum distance of the "Readmitted layer" of a particular factor. If enough points do lie within this distance then you could assume that this factor does have some sort of relationship.

For example, if we look at the "Readmitted point layer" and we take the factor measuring the distance to the nearest fast food outlet, using *Vector > Analysis Tools > Basic Statistics...* we can find the maximum distance.

We could then check if any points from the "Non-readmitted point layer" also lie within this distance to the nearest fast food outlet. You could use the **Field Calculator** to create a new field in which to hold a score of 1 (if the point does lie within the distance) or 0 (if it does not). You can use an expression like:

```
CASE WHEN "fast_food_distance_field" <= 'max_distance' THEN 1
ELSE 0
END
```

Decide on a threshold value such as 50 % or something (remember that you should justify this value). We could then count the number of points which scored 1 and calculate its percentage over the total amount of points. If it is 50 % or over then you could assume a relationship.

To count how many points have a score of 1, order the scores in the *Attribute Table*, select the top most row, find the last row with a score of one, hold `SHIFT` and select it to see how many points you selected in total. Then calculate the percentage of points selected with the total number of points:

```
('selected_points' / 'total_no_of_points') * 100 %
```

Repeat this process for the other fields and in the end, your "Non readmitted point layer" should have a score field for each influential factor. You could then create a final field to aggregate the scores (such as simply adding them up or calculating the average etc.) and creating a **Style** to visualise the final scores (again, this should be justified):

[image: Style]

For example, the higher the final score, the more likely the patient will be readmitted? There are countless statistical analysis you could do but hopefully this basic one will help start you off.

Comment: While interesting this approach need at many steps that the user make choices that will determine the result. However the goal here seemed to determine IF there is a relation to be found in the first place so maybe a more heuristic approach might be needed here.

Comment: @MarHoff - Yup, I completely agree, the user would need to justify their choices using this method. I just posted this as it was something I was asked to do a while ago which only required some basic statistics =)

Comment: Thanks for the idea Joseph.  I was actually thinking more along the lines of what @MarHoff was saying.  I was thinking about maybe doing some sort of calculation that finds the number of fast foot locations within a given radius of a readmission patient and comparing it to the number found in not readmission patients. Would you know how to do something like that?

Comment: @Mitchell - No worries buddy, you could perhaps take a look at this tutorial: [Performing Spatial Queries](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_spatial_queries.html). This involves **buffering** and doing a **spatial query** (it is done using a point and line shapefile but the principle can be applied).